# How rails app works with Unicorn and NginX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

i would like to know how a browser request flow b/w Nginx and Unicorn to work with rails app? Explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Being newbie does not excuse you from doing your own research.

Comment: i googled it alot. i haven't got good answer. if you find post it here . it helpful to all @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: This might be helpful: http://2ndscale.com/rtomayko/2009/unicorn-is-unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very generic question, thus a generic answer:

Nginx is usually set up as a reverse-proxy and static asset server.

```
Browser -(http)-> Nginx -(http)-> Unicorn worker -(rack)-> rails app
```

All unicorn workers share the same listening socket, balancing is done by OS via simple rule of 'first come - first serve'